# r - Problem with dummyVars when a level is not in test set

Tags: r, r-caret, training-data, dummy-variable, dummy-data

I have several training/test partitions. In one partition one variable has only two levels and it is higly imbalanced. The problem is, in the test set there is only one level for all of the rows, and it gives problems

As I understand, and works for other datasets, i should do this

```r
  dummyfier = dummyVars(~ ., train_char)
  train_char = predict(dummyfier, train_char) %>% data.frame()
  test_char = predict(dummyfier, test_char) %>% data.frame()
```

The problem is that i get the following error

```r
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I leave an example

```r
   train_char <- data.frame(da_b45 = c("N", "N", "S", "N"))
   test_char <- data.frame(da_b45 = c("N", "N", "N"))
   dummyfier = dummyVars(~ ., train_char)
   train_char = predict(dummyfier, train_char) %>% data.frame()
   test_char = predict(dummyfier, test_char) %>% data.frame()
```

As i understand, the training set need to have the values of the possible variables, and the test set should only check which variable is.
I really don't understand this behavior

Comment: Your code works for me with dummy variable output as expected. Maybe I am misunderstanding the question?

Comment: If your test data is small, then you may get a partition of train and test where the number of levels of a particular variable are not the same (as your example illustrates).